# Know React Component expected props from another Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Is there a way to list the expected props of a component A or B from another component C?

Why ? to dynamically add/remove Components and their props using User input.

Is it possible ? All I need, is to know which props each Component expects.

A and B accept different props. Ex:

```
 <A bar="foo"/>, <B baz=5 other="thing" />
```

**Hypothetical sketch:**

```
import A from "A"
import B from "B"

class C extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const props_for_A = A.props; // ??
        const props_for_B = B.props; // ??

        const user_input_props = [];

        const _flag = prompt("Insert Component A or B ?")
        switch(_flag) {
            case A:
                // Get the props for A
                forEach(prop in props_for_A)
                    user_input_props[prop] = prompt(`Please input ${prop}`);          
                break;
            case B:
                // Get the props for B
                forEach(prop in props_for_B)
                    user_input_props[prop] = prompt(`Please input ${prop}`);          break;    
        }                       
    }

    render() {
        switch(_flag) {
             case A:
                 return <A ...user_input_props />;
             case B:
                 return <B ...user_input_props />;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: I have a library of React components that can be placed into a container using a GUI, imagine a Component drag-n-drop web interface. And having this list, the user can edit their props dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over `A` and `B` components you could add any static var to it for example acceptedProps

```
A.acceptedProps = [ "bar" ]
B.acceptedProps = [ "baz", "other"]
```

And then just change your code to check for `acceptedProps` instead or props

```
 const props_for_A = A.acceptedProps
 // ....
```

If you don't have control over `A` and `B` you could agree on using [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) and then your code would be

```
const props_for_A = Object.keys(A.propTypes)
const props_for_B = Object.keys(B.propTypes)
// ....
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks !, This is very useful and helps me achieves my goal

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve what you want, you have to rewrite all of your components...

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  if(typeof props.name === 'undefined') {
    console.log('name is missing');
  }
}
```

You could check in the constructor of your components, if the props are set. If not, you can notify the user.

To make this easier, check out this Codepen: https://codepen.io/JanickFischr/pen/xjbpXV

With this, you can simplify everything.